# No Internet on Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak with BT

Tags: networking, server, internet, dns, 16.10

Apparently, whatever it is that they've done with the DNS is now making it completely impossible to connect to the Internet. Granted, I don't know my way around the network configuration too well, and this will be down to BT blocking DNS servers that aren't theirs, but it would have been nice to have made it so I could turn it off.
So far I have tried setting my IP to static with a DNS of 8.8.8.8, and also used dynamic with that server as an additional to no avail. I have also tried turning off dnsmasq from the network manager config, but I didn't expect that to do anything.

I really do hope someone can help me with a work around that doesn't involve me downgrading back to 16.04. And changing my provider is a bit out of the question.

I will have hopefully attached an image, I'm having to use my phone to post this and the image upload system doesn't seem to work very well. But if not, whenever I try to access a website a bright blue image pops up, courtesy of BT Home Hub, that states:
"You are seeing this page because you are using a BT service which requires the use of BT DNS Servers and it appears that you are attempting to connect using a DNS server outside of our network."
Please note that I have Parental Controls and Web Protect turned off.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer. And maybe if it becomes a common problem, a bug report can be submitted.

Comment: Same problems here after upgrading to 16.10. The modem works find with another computer.

Comment: I assume that "BT" is your Internet Service Provider? Does it all work if you **don't** specify your own DNS servers, and just use BT's DNS servers? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema yes that's right, and it all works just fine on other computers. But since it made my desktop inoperable I have now reinstalled 16.04 which, again, works fluidly. At first it was set to default, which is DHCP and no DNS, my router automatically assigns it a static IP by checking the MAC address and uses built-in BT DNS servers. But even then it thought I was trying to access other ones. So I tried other settings, using static on the OS and assigning manual Google server addresses (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4). But like I said, nothing worked.

Comment: You may be confused. You should select **Automatic (DHCP)** and **NOT** try to use your own DNS server addresses. You should **NOT** try and use a static IP address with your ISP... you'll make them very unhappy with the problems that can cause.

Comment: @heynnema A static private IP, not public. I need a static one because my desktop is a Samba file server. Like I said though, DHCP was the default and that didn't work.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Are you specifying DNS servers in your router? Obviously BT doesn't want you to use anything but their DNS servers. Remove any DNS servers defined in your Ubuntu "Wired Connection" network profile, and in your router. Your /etc/resolv.conf should only contain 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @heynnema Yes that is the default. The router came as part of a package with BT and the DNS routes are theirs and permanent. You can't add or delete any on the router. The default settings on my desktop was to obtain a private IP through DHCP (but the router knows to only assign that computer with one address) and have no default or additional DNS servers. But whatever they've done to Ubuntu means that for some reason, BT thinks I'm trying to access one outside of their network.

Comment: Will it work if you select **Automatic (DHCP) addresses only** (or **Manual**) and put BT's DNS server addresses (comma separated)  into the **DNS server** field? Your /etc/resolv.conf should only show the two addresses, not the 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @heynnema yes I tried putting BT's DNS servers in the Ubuntu network settings with both DHCP and manually assigned IP addresses. Neither worked.

Comment: I'm stumped. Cheers, Al